# bytes-like object is required / ord() expected string of length 1, but int found (python 3.6)

Tags: python, encryption, ord

I'm trying to work with:
[softScheck/tplink-smartplug](https://github.com/softScheck/tplink-smartplug)

I'm stuck in a loop of errors.  The fix for the first, causes the other, and the fix for the other, causes the first.  The code is all found in tplink-smartplug.py at the git link.

```
cmd = "{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":0}}}"

sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd))

def encrypt(string):
    key = 171
    result = "\0\0\0\0"
    for i in string: 
        a = key ^ ord(i)
        key = a
        result += chr(a)
    return result
```

As it is, result = 'Ðòøÿ÷Õï¶Å Ôùðè·Ä°Ñ¥ÀâØ£òçöÔîÞ£Þ' and I get the error (on line 92 in original file: sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd)):

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

so I change the function call too:

```
sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd.encode('utf-8')))
```

and my error changes too:

> ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

I understand what ord() is trying to do, and I understand the encoding.  But what I don't understand is...how am I supposed to send this encrypted message to my smart plugin, if I can't give the compiler what it wants?  Is there a work around?  I'm pretty sure the original git was written in Python 2 or earlier. So maybe I'm not converting to Python 3 correctly?

Thanks for reading, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please give us the whole traceback, not just the message.

Comment: You're supposed to encrypt bytes, not text.

Comment: Why not encode the result of `encrypt` instead of passing `bytes` to it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist His encryption algorithm wouldn't be as useful for encrypting Unicode code points instead of bytes, so I think it makes sense to do it in the order he's doing it.

Comment: Pretty new here.  I wasn't sure how much of a document I could post.  That's why I posted the link to the git.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, the result of `encode` is a `str` byte-string, which is a sequence of 1-byte `str` values. So, when you do `for i in string:`, each `i` is a `str`, and you have to call `ord(i)` to turn it into a number from 0 to 255.

In Python 3, the result of `encode` is a `bytes` byte-string, which is a sequence of 1-byte integers. So when you do `for i in string:`, each `i` is already an `int` from 0 to 255, so you don't have to do anything to convert it. (And, if you try to do it anyway, you'll get the `TypeError` you're seeing.)

Meanwhile, you're building `result` up as a `str`. In Python 2, that's fine, but in Python 3, that means it's Unicode, not bytes. Hence the other `TypeError` you're seeing.

For more details on how to port Python 2 string-handling code to Python 3, you should read the Porting Guide, especially [Text versus binary data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data), and maybe the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) if you need more background.

---

One way you can write the code to work the same way for both Python 2 and 3 is to use a `bytearray` for both values:

```
def encrypt(string):
    key = 171
    result = bytearray(b"\0\0\0\0")
    for i in bytearray(string): 
        a = key ^ i
        key = a
        result.append(a)
    return result

cmd = u"{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":0}}}"

sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd.encode('utf-8')))
```

Notice the `u` prefix on `cmd`, which makes sure it's Unicode even in Python 2, and the `b` prefix on `result`, which makes sure it's bytes even in Python 3. Although since you know `cmd` is pure ASCII, it might be simpler to just do this:

```
cmd = b"{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":0}}}"

sock_tcp.send(encrypt(cmd))
```

If you don't care about Python 2, you can just for `for i in string:` without converting it to a `bytearray`, but you still probably want to use one for `result`. (Being able to `append` an int directly to it makes for simpler code—and it's even more efficient, as a nice bonus.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough response! Definitely helped.  However, I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation.